# How to disable the auto-postback for fixed div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

HTML Code:

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
     <asp:UpdatePanel id="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
     <div>
    <table style="height: 40px">
    <tr>
    <td>

    <asp:TextBox ID="t1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:DropDownList ID="dd1" runat="server" Height="24px" 
            onselectedindexchanged="dd1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="116px" 
            AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="41px" 
            onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="97px" 
            AutoPostBack="true" ></asp:DropDownList>
       <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
            onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="334px" 
            AutoPostBack="true" Height="59px"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="display" onclick="btn_Click" /> 
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
     <div id="PieChartExample">
            <table>
                <tr style='vertical-align: top'>
                    <td>
                        <div id="CategoryPickerContainer"></div>
                        <div id="SliderContainer"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td >
                        <div style="float: left;" id="PieChartContainer"></div>            
                        <div style="float: left;" id="TableContainer"></div>   

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                           <div id="table"></div>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

   </ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers>
  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn" /> 
 </Triggers>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

Its my for drop down and chart. All dropdown  AutoPostBack is "true"  so at each change of value my chart will refresh.I don't want to refresh .my chart should refresh only after click btn. Can anyone help me to achieve.

Comment: how can you bind data in your chart?

Comment: after clicking button..and  dropdown only data filtering.

Comment: Set `AutoPostBack="false"`

Comment: I cant do that, because for each change of dropdown i have to fill some data to other drop downs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Page_Load` put the chart loading code in `if(!IsPostBack)` block. And use `UpdatePanel` for `Partial PostBack`. So the entire page won't get refreshed.

Like

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
 <asp:UpdatePanel id="upForm" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <!-- Your HTML -->
  </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
 <Triggers>
  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn" /> 
 </Triggers>
</form>
```

Comment: I have one dout that, i am using the chart loading on button click. if i put the entire code inside the asp:UpdatePanel my button click will not work.so i kept outside the  asp:UpdatePanel its work fine but.entire page is refreshes.How to avoid.Any  method to avoid refresh.

Comment: @user3431717 Try using `Triggers` as I updated my answer with that.

Comment: Set `UpdateMode="Conditional"` for `UpdatePanel`. If not working try by removing `Triggers`.

Comment: I tried your code in my local machine. The button click is hitting the  break-point!!! There is no problem with the code. Try restarting the VS. Or put another button just below the existing one and try using it.

Comment: Thank you..i got to know that button works fine(by adding text box value).just confuse that it will works fine when button not inside update panel.

Answer (score 0):

Set `AutoPostBack` to `False`.

Alternatively.

You can keep AutoPostBack as true if you use UpdatePanels.

Refer here for information on using UpdatePanels.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx